# What to learn after elementary geometry?

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, advice

I'm in love with Euclidian geometry. It seem I mastered elementary geometry, the one that schoolchildren learn throughout school. But I want to proceed to learn it. Could you advice me something? As a reference frame, I have read "Elementary geometry for college students" by Alexander Koeberlein. I need something in Euclidian planimetry, just something more advanced. Thank you. That would be really helpful not only for me, but to those who have same type of problem I have.

Comment: Do you know how to analyse conic sections on an $xy$-plane? Are you specifically looking for an advancement of geometry? Or could it be another subject like calculus? — Also, never tell yourself you’ve “mastered” something; keep the mentality that you can always learn and always grow, keep questioning yourself, pay attention to others even if you don’t think they’re “masters,” and to summarise just never give up on learning something, even after you think you’re done.

Comment: What to learn after elementary geometry? Geometry! This has many areas, e.g., differential geometry, convex geometry, computational geometry, etc. There are elementary introductions for each subarea.

Comment: As many others, I am fascinated by math. Of course I want to learn calculus. No, I am not saying that I mastered geometry. I said It seems that I mastered elementary geometry. By elementary geometry I mean only one small thing :). 

Okay, perhaps I have to look to "other" geometries.

Comment: This makes no sense to me: "It seem I mastered elementary geometry, the one that schoolchildren learn throughout school. But I want to proceed to learn it." says you want to learn something that you've already mastered. Huh?

Comment: No, I suspect I am just bad at English, it's not my native. What I meant is that I want to proceed to learn Euclidian geometry, but more advanced one. oh okay. We surely do not learn all the concepts that exist in Euclidian geometry, only a small-tiny part of it. And I just think I know it well. But I don't know where to go next. Sure, I can discover for myself, but I think it also will be great if I would have say, some textbook or videolist or anything else which will guide me forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe old-fashioned geometric conics? For example, see

[Charles Smith's text](https://archive.org/details/geometricalconic00smitrich/page/n9)

[Cockshott/Walters' text](https://archive.org/details/treatiseongeomet00cockuoft/page/n5)

[Clement V. Durell's text](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.84621/page/n7)

[Francis Sowerby Macaulay's text](https://books.google.com/books?id=JoxGAAAAYAAJ)

Also, look through the books that you can find [here](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/browse?type=lcsubc&key=Conic%20sections) as well as [here](https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/browse?type=lcsubc&key=Geometry%2c%20Plane).